# Is Bell's Notion of "Abstract Set" Flawed?

Tags: set-theory, computability, philosophy

Consider the following definition of "abstract set" given by John L. Bell (who wrote the book "Set Theory:  Boolean-valued Models and Independence Proofs") from his preprint "Abstract and Variable Sets in Category Theory":

"An abstract set may be considered as what arises from a concrete set [a concrete set is, in Bell's terms, following Cantor, "a collection to a whole of definite, well-differentiated objects of our intuition or thought"--my comments will always be in brackets] when each element has been purged of all intrinsic qualities aside from the quality which distinguishes that element from the rest.  An abstract set is then an image of pure discreteness, an embodiment of raw plurality:  in short, it is an assemblage featureless but nevertheless  distinct 'dots' or 'motes' ["perhaps also as 'marks' or 'strokes' in Hilbert's sense" (this is his 'footnote 3')].  The sole intrinsic attribute of an abstract set is the number ["one would be justified in calling abstract sets what Cantor termed cardinal numbers" (Bell gives Cantor's definition of cardinal number as follows:  'Let M be a given set, thought of as a thing in itself, and consisting of definite well-differentiated concrete things or abstract concepts which are called the elements of the set.  If we abstract not only from the nature of the elements, but also from the order in which they are given, then there arises in us a general concept...which I call the power or the cardinal number belonging to M')] of its elements"

Given the above definition, let's consider the following countably infinite abstract set, formed from Hilbert's stroke "|":

{|,|,|,....}=B.

Some might complain that the 'set' B might not satisfy Extensionality (a possible problem with Bell's concept already), so I will recast B in a possibly more acceptable form--that of an '$\omega$-tuple':

<|,|,|,....>.

However, there is even a problem with this, as I will show as follows:

Consider an infinite time Turing machine T on whose tape a countably infinite number of "|"s  are written (one "|" to each square of the tape).  The algorithm T performs is simple--T erases every second "|" from its square (i.e. it erases the "|" from every even square of the tape.  Once done, it returns to the initial square and repeats the process, finding the second "|" and erasing it as well.  Each of the remaining countably infinite sequences of "|"s  is by definition a proper subset and identical to the original countably infinite sequence of "|"s that was originally on the tape so that T never halts, making the set of proper countably infinite 'subtuples' of <|,|,|....> the size of Ord, the proper class of all ordinals.  It is also interesting that since by definition of Jensen's rudimentary functions, <|,|,|,....> is a constructible set, yet seemingly by using the ITTM T one shows that T, in generating a proper subset of the power set of <|,|,|,....>, shows that the cardinality of this set of constructible 'subtuples' of <|,|,|,....> is greater than $\aleph_1$, a contradiction.

My question, then, is this:  Do the above considerations show that Bell's notion of abstract set is flawed, and if not, where are the flaws in my reasoning?

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by your criticism.  T has a countably infinite tape and can form countably infinite tuples.  By what principle do you produce more than countably infinitely many such tuples if you can only take countably many "steps" at a time.  You need a wholly new principle to get beyond $ \aleph_0 $, namely the principle of a forming the supremum of a set.

Comment: Won't $T$ halt after it returns to the beginning $\omega$ times? The first time through, it erases the mark in square $2$. The first time back, it erases the mark in square $3$; the second time back, it erases the mark in square $4$, and so on. So, after $\omega$ times back it will have erased all but the first mark, at which point it will no longer be making subtuples. Indeed, no matter how it tries to erase marks, as long as it removes at least one mark each time it cannot have $\omega_1$ or more iterations, far from Ord.

Comment: @CarlMummert:  T will actually erase the marks in squares 2,4,6,8,... and will return a copy of <|,|,|,....> and will do so every time.  That is why I say that the collection of countably infinite subtuples of <|,|,|,...> is equinumerous with Ord.

Comment: @Thomas Benjamin: if it removes at least one mark each time, it cannot possibly do that for $\omega_1$ times, much less for Ord times. There are only countably many marks for it to remove. Consider: *which* mark from the original sequence is the first one removed at stage $\omega_1$, assuming any mark is removed?

Comment: @CarlMummert:  So at what time (or put another way, at what pass of the operation of T) is the tape completely blank?

Comment: @CarlMummert:  Please ignore the previous comment--Cameron already provided the answer.  But to help me complete my understanding on the issue of abstract sets, do either you or Cameron find any problem at all with Bell's definition?

Comment: @Thomas Benjamin: the tape will never be completely empty, because the first cell is never erased. But on the $\omega$-th iteration of the loop, every other cell will be blank, because cell $i+1$ is erased on iteration $i$.

Comment: As for Bell's definition, I was hoping that clarifying the algorithm would clarify your question. As it stands the Turing machine example seems to have nothing to do with Bell's definition; the question about the infinite time Turing machine would apply equally well to the *usual* conception of sets in ZFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should T's failure to halt indicate that the ***set*** of proper countably-infinite subtuples is a ***proper class***? For one, that's impossible by definition, and for another,  would you say that the real interval $(0,1)$ is a proper class? It can fairly readily be shown that said collection of subtuples is equinumerous to this interval.

Here's the idea. Any such subtuple will be an $\omega$-tuple, and every entry will either be blank or will be "$|$." A ready bijection, then, is to the set of binary sequences--that is, the set of sequences with every entry chosen from the set $\{0,1\}.$

Given a binary sequence $\langle x_n\rangle_{n\in\omega},$ it can be shown that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x_n}{2^{n+1}}$$ is a real number in the interval $(0,1),$ that every real number in $(0,1)$ can be thus obtained, and that distinct sequences yield distinct real numbers in this fashion. Moreover, as Carl points out, though T erases something (in fact, infinitely-many things) every time, the iteration is completely determined by the first thing that is erased, and in this manner, it can be shown that T *must*, in fact, halt on "step $\omega$" (a.k.a.: never halts in practice).

---

Now, in any set theory in which the reals comprise a proper class, it follows that said collection of subtuples is likewise a proper class, and (consequently) **cannot be a set**. In any set theory in which the reals are a set, so is said collection of subtuples. There is *no such thing* as a set that is a proper class (in a given set theory).

Comment: Aren't there models of set theory where one can revoke power set and add, say, Martin's Axiom for all cardinals and have the continuum (and therefore (0,1)) be a proper class as well?  If so, then why can't the collection of subtuples of <|,|,|,....> be a proper class?  And, yes, I'm interested in the details.

Comment: I'm afraid that the extent of my familiarity with Martin's Axiom is that I've heard of it. I'm completely unfamiliar with models of set theory in which the real line is a proper class. I will reiterate, though, that it is impossible for anything to be both a set and a proper class (regardless of the model in question), by definition. I will now expand my answer to provide said details.

Comment: My answer is now expanded. Please let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Certainly you are correct in stating that in models of set theory in which the real line is a proper class, the collection of subtuples cannot be a set by definition of proper class.  So at time $\omega$ the tape will be completely blank?

Comment: Not completely. The first spot will still have a $|$.

Comment: :Thanks for the clarification. It is appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm still mulling over Bell's definition. If any particular issues or observations occur to me, I'll append them to my answer and alert you to the changes.

Comment: Thank you.  I had other concerns, but  had thought that the failed ITTM example (which Carl was right in pointing out, could be applied to regular sets as well) was glaring enough to get people thinking (it, of course, fell through).  While you are mulling over Bell's definition, here are a couple of questions you might want to consider.  (1).  Given a countably infinite set of strokes {|,|,|,....} (since Bell considers this a set I will use the usual bracket notation), what is the cardinality of its power set (without using a bijection between {|,|,|,....} and {1,2,3,....})?

Comment: (2).  Even though Bell, following Cantor, defines abstract sets as having the order of its elements abstracted away, given two abstract sets A,B with cardinalities $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$ respectively, can one define an order on A,B that would make each a linear continuum?  If so, how would that relate (if at all) to the notion of 'adding Cohen reals' to A to form B?